# How to have a module load and define content in requireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want a module to both define content and require content. I have this:

test.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
    <script data-main="A" src="require.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

A.js

```
require(["B", "C"],function(B, C){
    alert(JSON.stringify(B));
    alert(JSON.stringify(C));
});
```

B.js

```
define(function(B) {
    alert("B");
    return {"B":1};
});
```

C.js

```
define(function(C) {
    alert("C");
    return {"C":1};
});
/*
require(["B"],function(B){
    alert(JSON.stringify(B));
});
*/
```

But how do I get C to load B, and use it as part of what it defines?

Thanks

Comment: You can define "B" as a dependency while defining module "C". Take a look [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep)

Answer (score 0):

Just list the module `B` as a dependency and set a parameter on your factory function:

```
define(["B"], function(B) {
    alert("C");
    alert(JSON.stringify(B));
    return {"C":1};
});
```

(The function you pass to `define` is commonly called the "factory function" because it *builds* the module.)

In your example code for `B` and `C` you set a parameter on the factory function that is the same name as the module *being defined*, like this: `define(function(C) {` *This is useless.* Since you do not give `define` a list of dependencies before the factory function, it will be called with an empty parameter list and the parameter will have the value `undefined`. The parameters on the factory function make sense only insofar as they are filled when RequireJS resolves the dependency list.